# Concepts behind augmented matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

Apparently the strategy for finding a general solution to the equation $Ax = v$, where $A$ is some $m\times n$ matrix, $x$ is an unknown vector of dimension n, and $v$ is not the zero vector, is to turn $v$ into an extra column of A (resulting in an augmented matrix, $aA$) and then simply proceed with the usual technique on $aA$ by putting $aA$ into row-echelon form. **But why does this work**? If I try to answer this question myself, the answer I give is because $Ax = v$ represents a system of equations, and moving $v$ from the right hand side of this system to the left does not change it. But in order to actually do that I think you'd have to subtract $v$ from both sides of the system, which would mean you should have $-v$ as the extra column in $aA$ and not $v$; but this is not how it works.

Where does my reasoning go wrong? What is the correct explanation for why performing row operations on $aA$ gives you the general solution to $A$?

Comment: You want to perform the operations that are required to put the matrix into row-echelon form on the RHS as well, so that the two systems are equivalent.

Comment: "but this is not how it works" [citation needed]. This is in fact exactly how it works, but we avoid writing the negative sign to simplify the notation. (In this logic each row in reduced echelon form will represent e.g. $x-a=0$ instead of $x=a$, which is why your answers aren't all accidentally the wrong sign.)

Comment: You could solve $Ax = v$ using row reduction just fine without introducing this augmented matrix. But eventually your hand would get tired, and in order to save writing you would decide to just write down the augmented matrix and do row reduction (exactly the same steps you were doing before) without bothering to write down all the variables and equal signs at every step.

Answer (score 3):

Using augmented matrices is just a nice way to encode simultaneous equations. And row operations are just a nice way to encode the operations we can do with equations, e.g. multiply both sides of an equation by a constant, add two equations together etc.

Take the example:

$$2x+2y=2\\
x-y=1.$$

This is a super simple example that you can solve in your head, but let's use this just to parse out what's going on behind the scenes of row-reducing an augmented matrix.

We could manipulate these equations as follows:

1. Divide the first equation by $2$ so your equations are now

$$x+y=1\\
x-y=1.$$
2. Take the second equation, subtract it from the first and divide it by 2 so your equations are now

$$x+y=1\\
y=0.$$
3. Take the first equation, subtract it by the  second so your equations are now

$$x=1\\
y=0,$$

and we solved the simultaneous equations.

All the above can be encoded by row operations on an augmented matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 2 &2 &|2\\1&-1&|1 \end{bmatrix}\overset{R1'=R1/2}{\longrightarrow} \begin{bmatrix} 1 &1 &|1\\1&-1&|1 \end{bmatrix}\overset{R2'=(R1-R2)/2}{\longrightarrow} \begin{bmatrix} 1 &1 &|1\\0&1&|0 \end{bmatrix}\overset{R1'=R1-R2}{\longrightarrow} \begin{bmatrix} 1 &0 &|1\\0&1&|0 \end{bmatrix}$$